# Encoding video on H.263 to send over RTP

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I'm developing an application to send video over RTP to a client that can play only H.263 (1996) and H263+ (1998).

To do this i've encoded the video using libav following these steps: (this is only part of the code)

```
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
Fmt = av_guess_format("rtp", NULL, NULL);
...
st = add_video_stream(FmtCtx, CODEC_ID_H263);
...
avio_open(&FmtCtx->pb, rtp_url, URL_WRONLY)
```

To finally enter a loop where i encode the video, the problem is that the stream generated by this program is encoded in **H.263-2000** (or H.263++) which the other side cannot undertand, even though i use CODEC_ID_H263 or CODEC_ID_H263P in the initialization the same thing happens.

Is it possible to encode in those old H.263 versions using libav? i havent managed to do it not even using ffmpeg commands. The stream is always h.263-2000 (PT=96)

Comment: Is your video is in one of the following resolutions: 128x96
176x144
352x288
704x576
1408x1152?

Comment: Yes, it is 176x144, if i use another size for CODEC_ID_H263 it fails (not for CODEC_ID_H263P) but it sends it in H263++ anyway

Comment: Hmm, could be a bug in libav... seems that `h263_plus` is never set to 0 in the encoder section of the code. So it could be that it is initialized with garbage and then `if (h263_plus)` condition renders true...